# How to apply background Image on ScrollView android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to apply background image on Relativelayout Under ScrollView.
The Image Appear on XML View but Not Appear on Actual device.

I have added ImageView on Ralativelayout

1. ```
       >

       <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"

           android:id="@+id/parentView"
           >
    <ImageView
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"
               android:src="@drawable/cloudbg"
               />

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:id="@+id/vo"
               android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout"
               android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
               android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="100dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:text="XYZ"
                   />

               <TextView
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:id="@+id/textvo"
                   android:text="Voter Number"
                   />

           </LinearLayout>


          </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
   ```

Thanks

Comment: if you want to give image for relative layout try proviidng background for that avoid the imageview

Comment: You want fix background ?

Comment: Yes I want to fix backgroud

Comment: you can give the `background color to your parent layout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can try this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/cloudbg">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/vo"
        android:layout_below="@id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="XYZ"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textvo"
            android:text="Voter Number"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `android:background="@drawable/background_image"` attribute in Relative or Linear Layout tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set background for scrollview
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```